# linux + write syntax in visudo

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo

Nplt user not have the permission to run the command **crontab -l**

so I add this lines in visudo

```
Nplt ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: crontab -l
```

but I get this error

```
isudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 21 <<<
What now? ^Cvisudo exiting due to signal: Interrupt
```

what is wrong in my syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Nplt ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab -l
```